# How to search "\0" in a binary file?

Tags: c++

I have an .idx file, I want to read this file using C++. All items in that file separated by \0 sign. I want to get that item list. I tried to implement it as below:

```
while (file.read(buffer, sizeof buffer), chars_read = file.gcount()){

            string search_term = "\0";            
            string contentElement = buffer;

            string::size_type  foundoffset = contentElement.find(search_term);

            if (foundoffset != string::npos){
                //Do something...
            }
         //code continue here.
         .....
}
```

But in C++, "\0" considered as null, If you have experience with C++, please instruct me how to do it. Note that this idx file is binary file.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `std::string` on binary files. If you work with raw char array, seek in it, for example with `std::find`.

For example:

```
const char* end = buffer + chars_read;
const char* ptr = std::find(buffer, end, '\0');

if(ptr == end) {
    // not found
}
else {
    // ptr points to null character
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to extract the text from beginning to the pointer ptr above. Also idx file has the format of one element:  word \0  - 4 bytes number - 4 bytes number   (\0 is the sign to end a word, a number with 4 bytes, then another number with 4 bytes). Can you instruct me how to get word, numbers in that binary file ? Thanks so much!

Comment: I solved this. sorry for asking too easy question! I'm new with developing C++

Answer (score 3):

If `buffer` is a character array (e.g. `char buffer[...]`) then the construction of the `contentElement` string will only read until the `'\0'` in `buffer`.

However, there is a [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) which allows you to set the contents of the string with length, which you should use if the contained string can contain embedded terminator characters:

```
std::string contentElement(buffer, chars_read);
```

Though for your purpose I suggest you stay away from `std::string`, and just search in the buffer directly. For example with [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).